# Magento 2 : Too many redirects in admin login screen

Tags: magento-2.0.4, system-configuration

Recently, i have moved the server of my magento2 project. After moving to different server following steps i have taken.

1) Configured the Base URL in

```
core_config_data
```

2) Clear the Magento 2 Cache (Remove all the content inside `var` directory)

3) Perform `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

4) Clear Browser Cookies and cache.

**Result**

chrome says `This webpage has a redirect loop` for only admin screen while frontend working fine. I have checked with the other browsers but it has similar message of `TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Prompt response to this issue will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked this a while ago, but I see that it is still unanswered.

You did the correct thing to change the Base URL in the core_config_data table.  I would make sure to double check that you updated both the secure URL and the base URL.

But the issue seems that the admin login screen is stuck in a redirect loop.

I'd recommend checking the app/etc/env.php file to see what the backend name for the site is set to:

```
'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin', //keep your custom url name here
  )
```

The next place I'd look is at the URL rewrite table to make sure that there isn't a special rule that is redirecting to the older location.

And if this doesn't fix it, then this is likely an .htaccess rule that may be stuck in a loop.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I have a similar problem, and nothing you write seem to help. The base URL is correct (that's why the frontend opens all right), frontName is "admin", URL rewrite table was truncated, and it is not an .htaccess problem because the redirection headers are fiven by the Magento PHP scripts.

Comment: OK, the problem in my case was hostname/domain name containing an underscore "_", which is not allowed for hostnames (and `filter_var($routePath, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` returns false).

Answer (score 1):

Do not keep '_' in your vhost url.

www.a_bc.co/admin  (Won't work)

to

www.abc.co/admin (Will Work)

[Magento 2 Admin ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126813/magento-2-admin-err-too-many-redirects)