# Magento 2 Admin ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: admin, magento-2.1

This problem looks like the case of using `http://localhost` as domain as found the issue:
[magento 2 Error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94722/magento-2-error-err-too-many-redirects)

But in my case the base-url is: `http://m2test_bd.mac0004.isaac.local/`

When I make a clean install on this URL and open (in Chrome of Firefox):

`http://m2test_bd.mac0004.isaac.local/admin/`

I get redirected to:

`http://m2test_bd.mac0004.isaac.local/admin/http:/index/m2test_bd.mac0004.isaac.local/admin/admin/index/index/key/8028086a452629a2b24de1fca7faaa78009a188619fdc2558c10e78f5eb18a0a/`

And get the notice:

```
The m2test_bd.mac0004.isaac.local page isn’t working

m2test_bd.mac0004.isaac.local redirected you too many times.

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing or is going wrong?

Comment: check my answer at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90456/magento-2-admin-this-webpage-has-a-redirect-loop/90463#90463

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the Magento 2 Admin can't handle the use of an underscore `_` in the URL.

The frontend has no problems with it and a cookie has been planted there with the correct domain - no sweat.

The backend, however, appears to handle this differently and trips over the underscore in the domain name. No cookie had been planted at the backend either, probably triggering the same problem as the `http://localhost/' problem ([magento 2 Error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94722/magento-2-error-err-too-many-redirects))

Using the URL `http://m2dev.mac0004.isaac.local/` had no problems.

Answer (score -1):

You remove sub dir from `var/cache` directory

```
rm -R var/cache/*
```