# Magento2.3: This page isn’t working, 127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times

Tags: admin, magento2.3, login, cookie

I'm facing one of the known issue that is **127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times** and tried to solve it by following as per the solutions given but those are all not working for me:

[Magento 2 : Too many redirects in admin login screen](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117029/magento-2-too-many-redirects-in-admin-login-screen)

[Magento 2 Admin ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126813/magento-2-admin-err-too-many-redirects)

I'm not sure whether this problem is due to improper configuration.

Could anyone please guide me to rectify this issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked  "cookie_domain" within the "core_config_data" table?

Comment: Should I enable It or I have to set it disable?

Comment: **Found a good answer! this worked for me** [solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/331650/94722)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to run below command once

```
php bin/magento config:set web/secure/use_in_adminhtml 0
php bin/magento config:set web/cookie/cookie_domain ''
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I have run the commands as you suggested but still getting the same error.

Comment: You get this issue after adding admin details and when you press on login button ?

Comment: try to run this command once and run deployment commands **php bin/magento config:set web/cookie/cookie_domain ''**

Comment: Did you tried this one ?

Comment: Yes, I have run this command, php bin/magento config:set web/cookie/cookie_domain, but got error "Not enough arguments (missing: "value")". So I have manually find out the path in database and given the full path as http://localhost/sitename

Comment: Please set NULL there.

Comment: then run all deployment commands once and then check

Comment: After changed the path, I can see the admin panel window is opened but when I try to login using the credentials, it says the below error: "Element 'add': Duplicate key-sequence ['Butterfly::top_level'] in unique identity-constraint 'uniqueAddItemId' "

Comment: Please find this key in your module **top_level**

Comment: How can i rectify that error?

Comment: that is coming twice so that issue is coming there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101831/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-siva).

Comment: Got any solution @Siva ?

Comment: Yes, finally it worked!!! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome Buddy. :)

Comment: it's not working with me :(

Comment: @huykon225 what error you're getting after changing above value? Same error?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya Exactly. I am facing with this error. I am using theme Codazon then I move my root site to a subfolder then it's occuring.

Comment: Clear your browser cookie and cache once and check, otherwise check cookie domain in your magento database core_config_data table once.

Comment: I did but still not working. Do you think anything else solution?